# Mass attached to another mass hanging from a hole in a table

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mass

I've been trying to understand the setup for the Lagrangian for this question from Morin:

[image: Problem description]
My issue is why would the mass ever rotate, assuming we release it from rest? Why does the setup of the Lagrangian assume this if it isn't specified anywhere except vaguely in the image? I get how to solve the problem and everything, but I would really like any insight on the setup.

Comment: The problem doesn’t say anything about releasing it from rest.

Comment: Then why can't the mass on the bottom be oscillating in some way as well? Why are we assuming no angular motion for one and not the other?

Comment: Because the problem says “Assume that $M$ moves in a vertical line only” while all it says about $m$ is that it “is free to move on a frictionless table”. The problem-writer simply decided to constrain the motion of $M$ to be linear and the motion of $m$ to be planar, to make the problem easier. You have to pay careful attention to what the problem says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only force acting over the mass $M$ is the tension force of the rope. If rope starts in a vertical position and the mass $M$ has no horizontal velocity, the rope will be vertical at all times. This means that $M$ will only suffer a vertical force, so the horizontal component of $M$ will always be zero. Therefore, you don't need to consider an additional coordinate to specify the angle the hanging part of the rope has.

You could always consider the complete problem and solve it for a general case, but the problem clearly states that the motion of $M$ is restricted to a vertical motion.

Answer (score 0):

If the mass m , on the table doesn't rotate , the mass connected with cord, M ,wouldn't be hanging. The gravitational pull on M is only balanced by the centrifugal force due to rotation of m. This is the setup of the problem.